# Stop click event propagation on a label

Tags: jquery, events, click, stoppropagation

I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't stop the propagation when I click on the label.

```html
<label for="box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box" />
    Test
</label>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#box').on('click', checkbox);
    $('label').on('click', label);
});

function label(e) {
    console.log('label');
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function checkbox(e) {
    console.log('checkbox');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

When I click the label, the checkbox function is fired despite the `stopPropagation()` in the label function. It's a problem that seems simple, but the solution seems much less so...

Answer (score 2):

This happens because this is the default behaviour of the browser. You can associate a checkbox with the label in two ways:

1. Checkbox within a label like:

   ```
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="box"/>Test</label>
   ```
2. Or using the `for` attribute like:

   ```
   <label for="box">Test</label><input type="checkbox" id="box"/>
   ```

In both cases, the checkbox will be autochecked/un-checked on label click. This is also mentioned in [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).

So, in order to prevent this default action, you should use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) instead inside the `label` click like:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#box').on('click', checkbox);
  $('label').on('click', label);
})

function label(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('label');  
}

function checkbox(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("checkbox");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="box"/>Test
</label>
```

If you are looking for a simpler solution then you can separate the label and checkbox and remove the `for` attribute from the label like:

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
  <input type="checkbox" id="box"/>&nbsp;
  <label>Test</label>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice. I was about to post an answer much like this. I prefer yours, palaѕн

Comment: The problem here is that I need the default behavior. and your preventDefault() won't allow it. So this solution tells me that there's nothing really clean to really stop the propagation.

Comment: @amo You need to stop propagation of the `click` (by the user) on the label, which then triggers a `click` (by the browser) on the checkbox. So you just need to stop propagation of that event as well. Then all that remains is a `change` event on the `input` resulting in the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me

```
$('#box').on('change',function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop propagation of the `click` (by the user) on the `label`, which then triggers a `click` (by the browser) on the `input`. So you just need to stop propagation of that event as well. Then all that remains is a `change` event on the `input` resulting in the desired behaviour.

*(still kindof annoying, I know...)*

In the snippet below, note the difference between clicking the label vs. clicking the checkbox!

```js
let input = document.getElementById('box');
let label = document.getElementById('boxLabel');

// Stop user click from propagating
label.addEventListener('click', stopProp);
// Stop browser click from propagating
input.addEventListener('click', stopProp);

function stopProp(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target + ' Click stopped!');
}

input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target + ' Value changed!');
});
```

```html
<label id="boxLabel" for="box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box"/>
    Test
</label>
```

Or, if you don't want the click event *on the input*:

**Option A: Set a flag**

```js
let flag_ignoreNextClick = false;
label.addEventListener('click', function() {
    flag_ignoreNextClick = true;
});
input.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(flag_ignoreNextClick) {
        // Consume flag
        flag_ignoreNextClick = false;
        return;
    }
    //TODO do 'only on checkbox click' stuff here...
});
```

**Option B: Emulate toggle**

```js
label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent input click event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Emulate toggle
    input.checked ^= true;
});
```

Comment: How can one tell from documentation, and without experiment, that a if user clicks on a label, the browser generates a (separate) click on the INPUT element...Ah, from MDN: "(the resulting event is also raised for the input)".  Resulting event?  What 'resulting event'? MDN could be clearer, e.g., The browser itself creates a new event for the INPUT.  Anyway, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using

```
event.preventDefault();
```

on the item inside the label, did the trick